# sql server query show error incorrect syntax near order

Tags: sql-server

```
if 1=(select oneTimePayClass from tblClass where division=@CDivision) 
    print 'True';
else
    (select h.FeeHeadId,h.FeeHeadName,d.amount,d.FeeDefaultId 
    from tblFeeHead as h inner join tblFeeDefault as d on h.feeHeadId=d.feeHeadId 
    where d.InstituteId=@InstituteId and d.Standard=@Standard and d.Division=@Division and d.AcademicYear=@year and h.oneTimePay=@payFalse 
    order by h.orderNr);
```

When I remove `order by h.orderNr` then the query runs successfully.

But when I add `order by h.orderNr` then it shows:

> error incorrect syntax near order

Comment: remove the brackets from your final sql statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions.

Do it like this

```
if 1=(select oneTimePayClass from tblClass where division=@CDivision) 
    print 'True';
else
    select h.FeeHeadId,h.FeeHeadName,d.amount,d.FeeDefaultId 
    from tblFeeHead as h inner join tblFeeDefault as d on h.feeHeadId=d.feeHeadId 
    where d.InstituteId=@InstituteId and d.Standard=@Standard and d.Division=@Division and d.AcademicYear=@year and h.oneTimePay=@payFalse 
    order by h.orderNr;
```